# How to upload files to a related record using lightning components?

Tags: lightning, related-list, upload, record, lightninginput

I'm trying to upload a file to a related record using just the `<lightning:input>` component.

The `<aura: component>` includes the `force:hasRecordId` and by using `{!v.recordId}` I am able to target the parent id easily. However, I have a hard time targeting the id of the related record..

I've used `<force:recordData>` before to get fields from the related record but uploading files seem different.

I'm trying to avoid using `<lightning:fileUpload>` but if I do I've gone as far as this:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<lightning:fileUpload label="File Upload"
                      name="fileUploader"
                      multiple="true"
                      accept=".pdf, .png, .jpg"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}"/>
```

However I'm only getting the recordId from the parent record.
Is there any way I could target the child record?

Something like `{!v.recordId.Related_SubRecord__c}` doesn't seem to work.
Please help!

Comment: So are you saying that you have a component which displays the parent and the child records on the same component, and that you want to upload a file from the component and that it gets associated to one of the child records?

Comment: @JayantDas Yes that's exactly it! I could always manually copy/paste the child record id but I want to make it dynamic.

Comment: How will you know to which child record the file needs to be associated to? At any given point of time, you will have 1parent:Nchild records.

Comment: @JayantDas The child record's API is Related_SubRecord__c with the type SubRecord__c. I was wondering if there's way to target that one specific child record.

Comment: As long as you can get that field which contains the target child record's id, you can utilize [`lightning:fileUpload`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/example) here. Are you having trouble getting that field in your component? Posting some code here by [editing your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/247699/edit) will be helpful for anyone to be able to provide some direction.

Comment: I have added details as how you can achieve this as an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolling up information from comments:

1. You have a custom field on a Parent Object to determine a Child Record `Related_SubRecord__c`
2. You have a custom lightning component where you are displaying the Parent and the Child records, and you want to upload a file to the Child record as determined by the value in `Related_SubRecord__c`
3. You need to fetch the child record's field to be able to associate the uploaded file to that record

---

You are on the right track for this. You can use [`lightning:fileUpload`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/example) here to associate the uploaded file to the child record as long as you are able to get the field accessible on your component.

In your example, you can access the `Related_SubRecord__c` using [`force:recordData`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) as below. Declare an attribute `simpleRecord` and then utilize that in the `targetFields` attribute in `force:recordData`. This will give you the fields from the record, and that you can access it in your component.

```
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object" />

<!-- removed other attributes for brevity -->
<force:recordData aura:id="myRecord"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetFields ="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                  .... />

<!-- utilize Related_SubRecord__c's value as below -->
<lightning:fileUpload label="File Upload"
                      recordId="{!v.simpleRecord.Related_SubRecord__c}"
                      name="fileUploader"
                      multiple="true"
                      accept=".pdf, .png, .jpg"
                      onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}"/>
```

Comment: Amazing! This worked! I did have to add `fields="Related_SubRecord__c"` to the `<force:recordData>` but other than that it works perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes, actually you can use `fields` attribute too.